# React edit entire row of inputs, then update state in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a component, CalcTime, which holds the state which looks like this:

```
todos: [{name: 'firstmname', title: 'assistant', startTime: '0800', endTime: '1600'}, {name: 'secondname', title: 'boss', startTime: '0700', endTime: '1700'} etc...]
```

The createTask looks like this:

```
createTask = ({title, start, end}) => {
    this.state.todos.push({
      name,
      title,
      startTime,
      endTime
    });
    this.setState({
      todos: this.state.todos
    })
```

In component CalcTimeItem, I have passed down the state from CalcTime, and I want to render an entire row of inputs when the main edit button is clicked. Then I want each input field to display it's current value, and when changed and the save button is clicked, I want to pass these new values to the state of CalcTime.

I realise it's necessary to have the saveNewState functionality on CalcTime, and pass it down to CalcTimeItem. But I can't for the life of me figure out how I can render each input field, and to connect each field's value with the saveNewState functionality. Has anyone done this before? I've tried to map, and to do Object.keys(obj).map() it but these concepts are still a bit too new to me.

EDIT: The CalcTimeItem renderfunction looks like this:

```
renderEditInputs = (e) => {
    let o = this.props.state[e];
    let r = FUNCTION HERE
    return(
      <div>{r}</div>
    );
  }
  renderTaskSection = () => {
    const {title, start, end}= this.props;
    if(this.state.isEditing){
      return(
        <div class="flex row">
          <form onSubmit={this.onSaveClick}>
            {this.renderEditInputs(this.props.id)}
          </form>
        </div>
      )
    }
return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onEditClick}>Edit</button>
        <button onClick={this.onDeleteClick}>Delete</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
  render = () => {
    return (
      <div class="flex row center" id={this.props.id}>
        {this.renderTaskSection()}
        {this.renderActionsSection()}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

EDIT 2: Got it to console.log the values of the object properties by doing the following:

```
renderEditInputs = (e) => {
    let o = this.props.state[e];
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function(key){
      var value = o[key];
      console.log(value);
    })
  }
```

Now it's about getting the function to render an  per object prop, and to create the saveNewState function which fetches the new input values and updates the state.

EDIT3: Got it working with the inputs:

```
onEdit = () => {
    console.log('testing onEdit functionality')
  }
renderEditInputs = (e) => {
    let array = [];
    let o = this.props.state[e];
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function(key){
      var value = o[key];
      console.log(value);
      array.push(<input defaultValue={value} key={key} onChange={this.onEdit}></input>)
    })
    return (array);
  }
```

So now I'm just pushing the inputs into the array "array", and then returning the array of inputs. However, onChange=}this.onEdit} does not work, the console gives me the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onEdit' of undefined".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need something like:

```
var calcTimeItems = this.state.todos.map(function(todo) {
     return (<CalcTimeItem todo={todo}/>);
   });
```

This will give you an array of `CalcTimeItem` components with todo props, which you can then render.

Comment: Thanks for your input! If you see the updated post, you'll find the r function. This is where I plan do to the edit funcitonality, and have a callback function which looks something like this.props.saveNewState, which will be a function passed down from the CalcTime component.